# Account Sharing

Tags: security

I have a user in a role.  How do I limit them to viewing the accounts of those below them by Type?
Account Type = In Process Client, Active Client and Inactive Client.
I've Set up their profile to be 'Read' only on Account.
Also, I have an account sharing rule that is supposed to allow their role to have read/write access to account types: In Process Client, Active Client and Inactive Client.
They're still able to see the Accounts below them with other Types from the picklist.  Marketing, Sales…etc.

Comment: When you say below them do you mean Account records owned by users below them in the role hierarchy?

Comment: I would stop, Grant Access With Role Hierarchy , and look into Criteria Based Sharing

Comment: Yes, users below them in the role hierarchy.  It appears that you cannot disabled Grant Access with Role Hierarchy on a Standard object.

Comment: Is there a lag time in recalculating?  It seems that the logic works for new records, but some of the existing records slip through the sharing filtering.

Answer (score 0):

As been said you can't disable hierarchy access in standard objects.
As Salesforce mention all the time, role hierarchy NOT EQUAL organization role.
So if something like that needed, you should re-design your role hierarchy for that purpose.
A solution for your issue could create a new top hierarchy for those users + criteria-based sharing rule.

From trailhead:(https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/data_security/data_security_roles)

> ...But role hierarchies don't have to match your org chart.
>       Each role in the hierarchy just represents a level of data access that a user or group of users needs.